# How does P(T|D) + P(T|~D) = 1?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

I was reading the [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033400.do)
I came across the conditional probability. The statement is:

> Imagine a certain disease that affects 1 in every 10,000 people. And
>   imagine that there is a test for this disease that gives the correct
>   result (“diseased” if you have the disease, “nondiseased” if you
>   don’t) 99% of the time.

T = Test result is positive.
D = Person is diseased.

So, P(T|D) = 0.99 and P(D) = 0.0001. The author calculated P(D|T) by Bayes theorem.

> P(D|T) = P(T|D) P(D) / [P(T|D)P(D) + P(T|~D)P(~D)]

For that, he calculated different probabilities.i.e.

- P(~D)= 1- P(D) = 0.9999
- P(T|~D) = 1 - P(T|D) = 0.01

I could understand intuitively that `P(~T|D) = 1 - P(T|D)`.
But I am unable to understand how `P(T|~D) = 1 - P(T|D)` is valid?
Can somebody explain mathematically?

P.S. The snapshot of the book snippet is:
[image: Probabilty]

Comment: ... It isn't true in general; in this case the "gives the correct result (...) 99% of the time" sentence makes two distinct things the same, which is why the result holds in this particular case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, P(T|~D) ≠ 1 - P(T|D).  To see why, suppose (1) the test results were completely independent of the disease and (2) the test is positive 25% of the time.

(1) implies that $$P(T|\lnot D) = P(T|D) = P(T).$$  If the test results are completely independent of the disease, then it doesn't matter what the disease state is.  Then the equation you're asking about becomes
$$P(T|\lnot D) =^? 1 - P(T|D)$$
$$P(T) =^? 1 - P(T)$$
The second version is true if, and only if, P(T) = .5.  In particular, filling in the value from (2), 
$$.25 ≠ 1 - .25 = .75.$$

It looks like the book section you were reading is [here](https://library.oreilly.com/book/0636920033400/data-science-from-scratch/37.xhtml?ref=toc#bayes_theorem).  I don't see where the author is assuming that P(T|~D) = 1 - P(T|D).

Maybe you're getting confused by the way the author moves between two versions of the [total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).  One version is
$$ P(F) = P(F,E) + P(F,\lnot E).$$
The second is
$$ P(F) = P(F|E)P(E) + P(F|\lnot E)P(\lnot E).$$

The first version expresses the probability of F in terms of two *conjunctions*:  F-and-E, F-and-not-E.  The second version expresses the probability of F in terms of two *conditional probabilities*: F-given-E and F-given-not-E.  The definition of conditional probability makes them equivalent.  But it's important to note that the conditional version includes the marginal (unconditional) probabilities of E and ~E.

Another potential point of confusion is that the author does most of the calculation in non-percentage numbers (.99 rather than 99%), then reports the final value as a percentage (.98% rather than .0098).

Comment: I inferred `P(T|~D)= 1 - P(T|D)` because the author has calculated P(T|~D)=0.01 and P(T|D)=0.99. So, I became confused that how he calculated `P(T|~D)=0.01`.

Comment: The author assumes that the test "gives the correct result (“diseased” if you have the disease, “nondiseased” if you don’t) 99% of the time."  That is, P(T|D) = .99 and P(~T|~D) = .99.  So the equation they use is P(T|~D) = 1 - P(~T|~D).